# How do I include java stuff in .jar files?

Tags: java, clojure

Okay. So here's my question: I am making a data parser in Clojure. One part of my program is that it has to be able to graph the data. I figure, I'll use jFreeChart. However, I have absolutely NO IDEA how to include stuff in JAR files. What I mean is: if I have a app.jar file in my classpath, I don't seem to be able to do:

import app.thing.thing2

without changing the classpath to be inside the jar file.

The idea here is that I don't think I can change my classpath since I need to set it to run Clojure (Or do I?). The global classpath is currently /usr/share/java.

And please don't ask me to use Maven, Ant or any project-building tool unless it is the only way to do this. This is a script for personal use that doesn't need or want a whole lot of overhead.

I wonder if I should just unpack every JAR file, so that I can reference the directory structure? Is this bad?

Let me know if you need any clarifications!

Comment: Does the JAR file work for compiling/running Java code? Maybe the problem is the JAR itself, in that it was not intended to be added directly to a classpath (which would be a mistake IMO). If you let us know how the commands/tool you're using to run or compile the code we could probably be more helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The content of the (Java) `CLASSPATH` environment variable is available to Clojure so if you add your jar to the global classpath before to run Clojure, you'll "see" it:

```
export CLASSPATH=/path/to/jfreechart.jar:$CLASSPATH
```

But, in my opinion, this is not the "clean" way to add a jar to Clojure's classpath (because this makes the library visible to **any** Java program and may not be desired). Instead, you should use the `CLOJURE_EXT` environment variable. This is how this variable is documented:

```
# CLOJURE_EXT The path to a directory containing (either directly or as
# symbolic links) jar files and/or directories whose paths
# should be in Clojure's classpath. The value of the
# CLASSPATH environment variable for Clojure will be a list
# of these paths followed by the previous value of CLASSPATH
# (if any).
```

On my system, it is defined as below:

```
export CLOJURE_EXT=~/.clojure
```

So, to add jfreechart.jar (or any other library) to Clojures's classpath, copy it (or add a symlink pointing to it) in the directory defined in the `CLOJURE_EXT` variable.

And by the way (I'm sorry but your question is not that clear), if you want to bundle some Java classes into a jar, the command is something like that:

```
$ jar cf myjarfile *.class
```

You'll find documentation of `jar` - the Java Archive Tool - [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/jar.html).

Comment: This answer was just what I was looking for.

I do sometimes have trouble formulating clear questions. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I completely respect your desire not to use a project management tool, though I just spent longer typing this sentence than it takes to set up leiningen. For your one-off script any tool is going to be overkill and Pascal Thivent's answer covers this very well. For people reading this question who perhaps want to produce a jar file, or easily load their Clojure into emacs/slime-swank I cant recommend leiningen too strongly.

Answer (score 1):

If you going to basics you can inline your classpath to include the hardcoded location of your jars, so if you on windows it will look something like

`java -cp .;%CLASSPATH%;C:/here/it/is/foo.jar com.foo.MyClass`

Comment: Except that the question is about Clojure if I'm not wrong so this doesn't help the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how clojure is run, but don't you just add the jar file to the classpath?

i.e.

```
/usr/share/java:/home/user/myjarfile.jar
```